# Cannot refresh page or type URLs manually for React Router Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When i follow a link to another component and then refresh the page, or try to type it manually it'll just take me to a blank html page and it won't load any of the content.

Here is my App component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: [],
      players: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadGames();
    this.loadPlayers();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.loadGames();
    }, 5000);

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.loadGames();
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  async loadGames() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/games');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    const sortedJson = myJson.sort((a, b) =>
      a.spectators > b.spectators ? -1 : 1,
    );
    this.setState({ games: sortedJson });
    console.log('updating')
  }

  async loadPlayers() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/playersList');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({ players: myJson });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <GameList players={this.state.players} data={this.state.games} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/players/:id">
            <Player />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Server has catch all at the bottom:

```
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../dist/index.html'));
});
```

Serving my index.html from dist:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
```

I would like to make it so that when I type in a url, for example:
http://localhost:3222/players/221666230 // should load the Players component with 221666230 as the id param instead of just taking me to a blank index.html page.

I've read other posts that mention having a catch all route, which I've included. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: By "catch all" I think it is meant you have a route that matches *anything* (by not specifying a path) so if no other routes match and get rendered by the `Switch` it will be rendered, typically as a 404 page. `<Route component={My404Component} />`

Comment: @DrewReese how would I modify my code to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Simply add a non-matching route (i.e. no path `<Route component={My404Component} />`) as the last route in your switch as a catch all if no routes above it are matched.